# How to override configuration of third bundle from a third bundle

Tags: symfony, config, fosuserbundle

I'm making a bundle in Symfony 4, but in my bundle I use FOSUserBundle.
So I would like to defined configuration for FOSUserBundle from my own bundle and not from the main configuration. How to do it ? It doesn't recognize the node

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_user" (in C:\wamp64\www\MyProject\src\CMSBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\fos_user.yaml). Looked for namespace "fos_user", found none

And if I load the configuration of FOSUserBundle (FOS\UserBundle\DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) in my CMSExtension.php

I'm getting this message

> The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.

**Structure**

```
/src
    /CMSBundle
        /Controller
        /DependencyInjection
            CMSExtension.php
        /Entity
        /Repository
        /Resources
            /config
                fos_user.yaml
                routing.yaml
                security.yaml
                services.yaml
        CMSBundle.php
```

**src/CMSBundle/DependencyInjection/CMSExtension.php**

```
class CMSExtension extends Extension {

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
        $loader->load('security.yaml');
        $loader->load('fos_user.yaml');
    }

}
```

**src/CMSBundle/Resourcers/config/fos_user.yaml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: src\CMSBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `CMSExtension` class, you can implement the `PrependExtensionInterface` and add a `prepend` method.

In this method, you'll be able to override the FOSUserBundle configuration:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $newConfig = [
        'db_driver' => '',
        ...
    ];

    $container->prependExtensionConfig('fos_user', $newConfig);
}
```

Look a [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) in the Symfony documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It works, but it's a little bit tricky, isn't ? Is there another way to override config with a yaml file ?

Comment: You can use the `Yaml` parser to transform your `fos_user.yaml` file into an array: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#reading-yaml-contents